# Use AnnotationReader under namespace

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, namespaces

I have a class under namespace framework\ext\Library and use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader, however when I try to create an instance of AnnotationReader, it throws a class not found exception.

```
namespace framework\ext\Library;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
class CommonFunction {
  public function getAnno(){
    ...
    $annotationReader = new AnnotationReader();
    ...
  }
}
```

the error throws

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader' not found
```

I have try to remove the namespace of my `CommonFunction` it works fine. How to fix it?